# Download MSBuild Build Tools for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have an old C++ project which requires Visual Studio 2013 to build.  I have 2017 installed.  How do I just download the MSBuild component for Visual Studio 2013 so that I can compile C++ projects?

Comment: Direct links can be found in https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadVisualStudioExpress.aspx You need Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows (Desktop) or you can use Community edition (if you meet Community edition requirements). If you are MSDN subscriber, you can also use Professional or another paid edition.